# Terminal Services on Windows Mobile - "Paste" doesn't preserve punctuation?

Tags: windows-mobile, clipboard, copy-paste, terminal-services, punctuation

I have here a Windows Mobile-based PDA (Mobile Compia M3 Sky) equipped with a barcode scanner. This barcode scanner works by reading the data from the scanner into the Clipboard and then simulating a Paste on whatever application is currently running.

The problem is, when you're using Terminal Services from the device and you scan a barcode containing punctuation (e.g. "A-2-C", "A-1-[") the punctuation gets stripped out before it reaches the server - i.e. the only things that make it to the server are the alphanumerics (i.e. "A2C" and "A1" respectively).

I have verified that the device does have the full barcode including punctuation in the clipboard - i.e. if I open up Notes on the device and scan these barcodes, they are pasted correctly (i.e. "A-2-C" and "A-1-[" respectively) and I can paste them again by tapping, holding and selecting Paste, or by pressing Ctrl+V on the soft keyboard.

However, for some reason, this punctuation appears to get stripped out by the RDP client on the device (mstsc40.exe) - it happens regardless of what application or OS the server is running [on].

Does anyone have any previous experience with this, or have any pointers?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was just a bad implementation of the RDP client on Windows Mobile 5. WM6 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can only suggest a workaround of using Virtual Channels to send over the data. Although not really an answer to your question it would be a better solution since copy/paste over an RDP connection is known to be buggy (see these links: [RDP Clipboard Fix](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/10/25/rdp-clipboard-fix/), [Why does my shared clipboard not work? (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2006/11/16/why-does-my-shared-clipboard-not-work-part-1.aspx) & [Why does my shared clipboard not work? (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ts/archive/2006/11/16/why-does-my-shared-clipboard-not-work-part-2.aspx))